# IndexedDB. Как обновить данные без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript

Пишу учебное todo-приложение на angular 2, с функцией локального хранения списка дел. Использую **indexedDB**.
Основные действия уже написал(**Create Read Update Delete**), все работает!
Но при добавлении нового элемента в список дел, чтобы получить его на странице нужна перезагрузка страницы =(

**Вопрос собственно такой: Можно ли как нибудь обновить базу данных, как только в ней произошло какое нибудь действие(без перезагрузки страницы)?**, будь то добавление данных или удаление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать конпку обновить(например), и кликая по ней делать Ajax-запрос в базу данных, ну а дальше я думаю вы уже сами разберетесь. 
[AJAX](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-intro)

Comment: Конечно же спасибо за ответ =), но я только что обнаружил что все и так обновляется) просто нужно **панель разработчика** перезапускать